# How would I change this MySql statement

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

Hi at the moment I am trying to create a login system but I am hitting a problem with setting privileges for the users this is the MySql statement that i am using to find out the username and password from phpMyAdmin database.

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I was wondering if someone could help me edit this code so that I can echo or print the account_type to the page so i can use it within a PHP if statement to restrict what the users see.

I have tried

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' and account_type ='myaccount'";    
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

this is the full pages code

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="127.0.0.0"; // Host name
$username="username"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

print_r($row);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;




//session_register("myusername");
//session_register("mypassword");
//echo "correct";
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Change to using MySQLi with prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm new to PHP so I don't know what that means. This is really my first project using PHP.

Comment: Google the suggestion if you don't understand them, don't do bad practice just because you're new, it's hard to get somewhere with that attitude. MySQLi and PDO are not outdated ways of doing database functionality.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `mysql_fetch_array()` call.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

After that you can access `$row` array; to see its contents use:

```
print_r($row);
```

To access specific field, use `$row['fieldname']`

Comment: I have just tried this and it still doesn't display the account type on the screen any ideas i have put my full code in the original post.

Comment: Not enough information. Does it redirect? What does it display?

Comment: it displays the username and the password but it doesn't display the account type i have tried it with and without the $row['fieldname'] and with and the account type doesnt show

Comment: Well, replace 'fieldname' with actual name of the field.

Comment: yes i did i replaced it with account_type that is what the column is in the database @ValPetruchek

Comment: this was correct i eventually got it working i used a different way to print it to the screen instead of print_r(row) and it is working perfectly now thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch that array from sql.

See the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)